# SWAN WAVE model: Strange result

Tags: oceanography, wind, waves, wave-modeling

I'm Ocean Engineering Master Student. I have some problems with my research. When I plot the result [image] it is rotated. The color blue one is land. This my script, what should I do to fix the problem?

```
    PROJECT 'tesis' 's2'
    
    $Input Data
    SET LEVEL 0.0 depmin 0.1 maxerr=1 inrhog=1 NAUT  
    MODE NONSTAT TWOD
    COORD SPHE 
    
    $Domain Model
    CGRID REG 78 -15.5 0.0 83 23 415 115 &
        CIRCLE 36 flow=0.04 fhigh=1
    
    $Bathymetri Input-
    INPGRID BOT REGular 77.4 -15.56 0.0 20207 5949 0.004167 0.004167 &
        EXCEPT -9999
    READINP BOTTOM -1.0 '1.txt' 2 0 FREE 
    
    $Wind Input
    INPGRID WIND REGular 78 -15.5 0.0 337 93 0.25 0.25 &
        NONSTAT 20190201.000000 6 HR 20190201.180000
    READINP WIND 1.00 'Feb1uv.txt' 2 0 FREE
    
    $Boundary Setting
    BOUND SHAP PM 
    
    $Initial Condition
    INITIAL DEFAULT
    
    $Paramater Setting
    GEN3 KOMEN AGROW
    WCAP 
    QUAD
    TRIAD
    BREAKING
    DIFFRAC
    FRICTION
    
    $ NUMERICAL CALCULATION
    
    PROP BSBT
    NUM ACCUR npnts=95. STAT mxitst=15

 $_________________ OUTPUT DISPLAY ______________________________________
BLOCK 'COMPGRID' NOHEAD 'coba1.mat' LAY 1 XP YP WIND HSIGN DIR PTHSIGN PTDIR OUT 20190201.000000 6 HR 
$end
COMP NONSTAT 20190201.000000 6 HR 20190201.180000
STOP
```

Comment: Maybe you have the wrong output layout? You are using LAY 1, whereas the documentation states `see command READINP (options are: [idla]=1, 3, 4). Option 4 is recommended for postprocessing an ASCII file by MATLAB, however, in case of a generated binary MATLAB file option 3 is recommended.`

Comment: Thanks, Ingvar Lukas for your reply but it doesn't work the result still same.